# Google maps acting weird in my app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, android-maps-v2

Hello I'm trying to implement google maps in my android app and I manage to do that at least partially.There are a lot of bugs in my map ( it won't show until you click few times on screen, you can't zoom , you can't move only press on screen and hope something will happen)
This is my code:

```
public class LocatorFragment extends Fragment implements   GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{
private  MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap map;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locator_fragment, parent, false);
    mapView=(MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();

    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    return rootView;
}
// This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
// Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      }

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return false;
}
}
```

This is my layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So when I open map fragment i get a empty grid then on each click on that grid it load a part of map :O it's really weird. And I can't zoom or move map

Comment: Why are you still using `getMap()`? That's deprecated. I suggest going over the Android Maps Quickstart to familiarize yourself with the latest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @McAwesomeville's answer.

You need to read through the updated [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_2_install_the_google_play_services_sdk). [`getMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#public-method-summary) was deprecated. Use [`getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) instead. The callback method provides you with a GoogleMap instance guaranteed to be non-null and ready to be used. It automatically initializes the maps system and the view.

Just have your Activity implemented the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface and then assign your googleMap reference in the `onMapReady()` callback.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

googleMap = map;

setUpMap();

}
public void setUpMap(){
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
}
```